# What is the meaning of "nice" in this song?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The song ["Her Majesty" by the Beatles](https://genius.com/The-beatles-her-majesty-lyrics) starts with: «Her Majesty's a pretty nice girl».
What is the meaning of the word «nice» in this sentence?
Does it mean she is beautiful or friendly?
More generally, how does one knows what is the actual meaning of this word?

Comment: Not in accord with the dictionary, the 2 answers below or any other contributor to this site, my late aunt who was an English teacher, recommended that "nice" be restricted to describing food and some other adjective be found to describe people, places or other things..

Comment: Well, I will make sure to abide by this recommendation when talking with you aunt!

Answer (score 2):

The word 'nice' is, one of the vaguest-meaning words in the English language. It just means 'approved of by the speaker in some way'. Students may be criticised by teachers for laziness if they use it when a more exact word would be better.

It may sometimes be possible to tell more exactly what the speaker's intent was by examining the context (surrounding or following words).

Your sister is a nice girl (she is kind to animals/pretty/laughs at my jokes/reads the Bible/supports my soccer team...)

My friend has a nice dog (it never growls at me/I like its colour/it is obedient/it wags its tail a lot...)

I have a nice car (it is comfortable/I like the colour or shape...)

In the case of pop songs, it is important to remember also that the words are usually added after the tune in composed (this is especially true of the Beatles). The words are often not expected to have very much literal meaning; their job is to fit the tune. Do not expect very much more meaning than (e.g.) 'Tra-la-la-la-la-la'.

[Why you should ban the word "nice" from your writing](https://medium.com/@katie.ginger/why-you-should-ban-the-word-nice-from-your-writing-7038aee07b66)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From the examples you give, it seems that «nice» usually refers more to the character than the visual appearance, is it correct? Concerning the song, I suspect that the Beatles are careful in their choice of words when talking about their queen. So do you think they mean "good looking" or "friendly" ?

Comment: @LouisCoulet - If we say a person **is** something, we are talking about a quality that they have. Note: 'the Beatles are...' - the Beatles group has not existed for more than 50 years, and half of them are dead. The Beatles just wrote some la-la-la words to fit the tune.   It could just as easily have been 'My sister has a very nice dog'. Don't over-think this.

Comment: "But I gotta get a bellyful of wine ... Someday I'm going to make her mine" is not a very respectful way to speak of your Sovereign. This was 1969 when the Beatles cultivated an anti-establishment image.

Answer (score 0):

"Nice" means what the dictionary tells you - *pleasant, agreeable*. It is a commonly used adjective, mainly because it fits so many contexts. You can say a person is nice, a meal is nice, the weather is nice. For that reason it is also sometimes considered a fairly bland adjective that requires vocal expression or an adverb to give it emphasis.

I suspect where you are confused is over the word 'pretty'. On its own, 'pretty' is an adjective, meaning *pleasing in appearance*. Again, it has a wide usage. But, 'pretty' can also be an *adverb of degree*, meaning to a fair extent. So, "*pretty nice*" means that the person or thing being described is pleasant or agreeable to a fair extent.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am not confused with the usage of «pretty» as an adverb, but I am trying to understand how to get the right meaning of the word «nice».

Comment: @LouisCoulet Look in a dictionary for some example uses of 'pretty' as an adverb. You'll find it pretty useful. Cambridge is a pretty good dictionary. I've been using it pretty much all my life.